# Json data not displaying in div on webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

(Solved my issue-this will stay up as a reference to how an Ajax call works)
I am just learning javascript and how to implement Ajax requests. I am creating a webpage and I want to use Ajax to grab data from a JSON file and display it on the page. I have a div element with the id of jsonpetdata and the JSON file is petinformation.json. I am not getting any syntax errors nor errors with javascript in the console so I have no idea why it isn't displaying data. I have a li in an ul with the id of "dog" and I set up a click event handler in jquery to grab data when clicked using ajax. I just want it to display the data in the empty div with the id of "jsonpetdata". Any help is appreciated.

```js
$("#dog").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "petinformation.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#jsonpetdata").html("");
      $.each(data, function() {
        $.each(this, function(key, value) {
          $("#jsonpetdata").append (
            value.name + "<br>" +
            value.title + "<br>" +
            value.paragraph + "<br><br>"
          );
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dropkick.css">
    <link href="jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Little Walker</title>
        <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dropkick.js"></script>
    <script src="js12/jquery.bxSlider.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script> <!--links the javascript file-->
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <div class ="topnav" id="myTab">
        <nav>
            <ul> <!--Creates navigation bar, sets the information page to the active tab-->
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li> <a class ="active" href = "Information.html" >Information</a></li>
                <li><a href = "Appointment.html" >Appointment</a></li>
                <li><a href = "About.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<main>
    <h1>Helpful Hints</h1>
    <p>This page is dedicated to offer you helpful information depending on what type of animal you have.</p>
    <label for="animal" id = "animal_label">Choose an animal to get information(you will be redirected to a webpage)</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="custom-select" id="custom-select"> <!--creates a drop down menu to select which animal you want more information on-->
    <select id="animal" name="animal" class="animal" required size="1" onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"> <!--redirects user to specified webpage on click-->
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="https://iditarod.com/ten-tips-for-taking-care-of-your-dog/">Dog</option> <!--depending on the selected animal, clicking on the item will re-direct you to a specific web page-->
        <option value="https://www.petsafe.net/learn/cats-101-basic-health-care-tips-to-keep-your-cat-healthy">Cat</option>
        <option value="https://www.petco.com/content/petco/PetcoStore/en_US/pet-services/resource-center/new-pet/eight-tips-to-keep-your-freshwater-fish-happy-and-healthy.html">Fish</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div id = "jsoninformation">
        <p>If you would rather not be directed to a website, you can get quick tips on your pets by selecting here.</p>
        <ul>
            <li id = "dog"><a title="dog">Dog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="jsonpetdata"></div>
    <div id ="bxslider">
    <ul id="slider">
        <li><img src = "images/dog.jpg" alt = "dog" ></li>
        <li><img src = "images/cat.jpeg" alt = "cat" ></li>
        <li><img src = "images/fish.jpg" alt = "fish" height = "300" ></li>
    </ul>
    <p id="pager"></p>
    </div>

    <!--<img src="householdpets.jpg" alt = "Household Pets" width = "800" height = "500"/>adds an image to the page-->
</main>
<footer> <p>&copy;littlewalkerco</p></footer>
</body>
```

```
JSON: {"pets":[
    {
        "name": "Dog",
        "title": "Caring tips",
        "paragraph": "1. Provide a protected and clean living environment for your dog 2. Always keep fresh water available. 3. Feed a quality diet and prevent obesity. 4. Have your pet examined by a veterinarian on a regular basis. 5. Let your dog exercise."
    }
]}
```

Comment: You have a syntax error

Comment: Please show us your HTML, including the ``<script>`` tag where you are calling this JS code. One red flag is that you're not specifying an error handler: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.

Comment: You need to import jquery. add this code to your file <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Can you please add a `console.log(data);` as the first line of code inside the `success: function(data) {`, and then please tell us what you see in the console.

Comment: Cesar, I do not have that exact src but I have already implemented jquery. It is a file: "jquery-3.4.1.min.js" I assume ajax came with this, or am I wrong?

Comment: Ivan86, I did that and nothing is in the console after the click event. I am not getting any errors either.

Comment: The `console.log(data);` should be the first line of code after `success: function(data) {`. Also, to make sure the success function is called, add `console.log("test");` right above `console.log(data);`. So if you don't see the string "test" in the console the success function hasn't even been called. It would help, as stated by others to include key parts of your HTML and an example of the petinformation.json file.

Comment: I will follow your advice when I get back in an hour or two and update with more information.

Comment: Ivan86, it appears the string test does not appear in the console so the success function has not been called apparently, but I thought it is a callback function so it should execute automatically on document load. I assume then, that it is not a success but a failure, in which case I don't understand how that's possible.

Comment: King11, can you elaborate?

Comment: Just used error to test if it is throwing an error instead of success and it seems to be failing. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this is failing? Maybe JSON syntax is the problem?

Comment: Update: changed the json file location and it randomly started working, no idea why. Thanks again for the time anyone put into looking at this, I guess this post will stay up to show an example of an ajax call.